# How to get expiry date of a Non-renewing subscription

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, in-app-purchase

I want to know how to check non-renewing subscription expiration for iOS7.

While doing receipt validation Iam getting SubExpDate = "";
After successful receipt validation I am getting data as

```
        CancelDate = "";
        OriginalPurchaseDate = "2015-04-17T09:56:14Z";

        OriginalTransactionIdentifier =
        ProductIdentifier = ;
        PurchaseDate = "2015-04-22T05:46:55Z";
        Quantity = 1;
        SubExpDate = "";
        TransactionIdentifier =;
        WebItemId = 0;
```

How to calculate expiry date? Any help to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [This documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW28) the receipt will never return the expiry date. Therefor you need to calculate it yourself. You can either create a backend service that keep the record of each product expiration duration or embed it directly in your app.

Comment: any idea to calculate expiry date?

Comment: I think you may be missing the point @user2931321. By the Apple definition of the non-renewing subscription, the app (i.e., your program) defines the expiry date for this kind of purchase. For example, in my app, I have non-renewinig subscriptions that last one year. Why do they last one year? Because that's how I defined it.